# Realtion between eigenvalues and determinant of symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

$A$ is a $n\times n$ real symmetric matrix with eigen values $a_1,\cdots,a_n$ then
which of the following statements true??

1. product of all eigen values < det(A)
2. product of all eigen values > det(A)
3. product of all eigen values = det(A)
4. If det($A$) = 1 then all eigen values of $A$ are equal to 1.

I tried trial and error method of $2\times 2$ symmetric matrix I get both option 2 and option 3 ??
But I am not sure what is the answer??

Comment: 3rd option is correct

Comment: how it will come In general it is not true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eigenvalues are the roots of $$ P(\lambda)= \det (\lambda I - A) = (\lambda - \lambda_1)(\lambda - \lambda_2)...(\lambda-\lambda_n)$$

Let $\lambda = 0$ and you get $$(-1)^n \det(A) = (-1)^n \lambda_1 \lambda _2...\lambda_n$$ That is $$\det(A) =  \lambda_1 \lambda
_2...\lambda_n$$
Thus option $3$ is the correct one.

Comment: Thank you Sir @Mohammed Riazi-Kermani

Comment: Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

Because this applies to every matrix only ONE of #1,#2, and #3 holds true.

Consider a diagonal matrix with entries being $\lambda_1, \lambda_2...$.

The determinant is equal to the product of the eigenvalues, so option $3$ is true.

Statement 4 is false because the product of eigenvalues can still be $1$ without all the eigenvalues being $1$.

---

Every symmetric matrix $S$ can be diagonalized, or written in the form $PDP^{-1}$, for some matrix P, and diagonal matrix D.

Then, $\det(S)=\det(P)\cdot\det(D)\cdot\det(P)^{-1}=\det(D)$.

And you can verify that the determinant of a diagonal matrix is the product of the eigenvalues.